# How to create a key/value modifiable system with Drupal?

Tags: drupal, dictionary, key-value

I just want to make a page where a moderator may edit a list of key/value corresponding to some string displayed on the site.
I really don't find module more user friendly than the module variable.
In addition, create a module just for that seems a little barbaric given the simplicity of the application.
Do you know any module able to do that on drupal 7 ?

EDIT : I finally created directly a module based on the variable module to manage a list of variable. Slightly longer than something ready but quite effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record. I would go with the [Data](http://drupal.org/project/data) module.